# react hooks inside conditional statement

Tags: react-hooks, conditional-statements

As per [Hooks Rules](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation), we are not allowed to use any hooks inside conditions. However the following example works and I am not quite sure why it DOES NOT error.

Could someone explain why there is no error in spite me using the hooks inside a if condition?

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

let trackChanges = true;

export default function Demo() {
    const [text1, setText1] = useState("First");
    function onText1Change(value:string){
        setText1(value);
        if (value.length > 8)
        {
            trackChanges = false;
        }
        else{
            trackChanges = true;
        }
    }
    if (trackChanges){
        useEffect(()=>
        {   return () => {
                document.title=`${text1}`;
            }
        }, [text1]);
    }
    return (
        <input onChange={e=>onText1Change(e.target.value)} value={text1}/>
    )
}
```

I have tried to write this code on VS code hoping it will error out, but to my surprise it is working rather than erroring out as pointed out by other StackOverflow questions and react documentation.
It only breaks in run time when the text1 value > 8. Some thing wrong with my lint settings? why is there no error to warn me according to hook rules.

Comment: You would definitely be seeing an warning message in console and also you can use this plugin to catch this errors within your code using https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks

Comment: Not quite sure why it is downvoted. My question is correct, if it doesn;t highlight this as an error where it is supposed to on this simple case, I am worried that it won't identify the error in much complex cases. It appears that my ESLint setting is not setup properly to error out in advance in VS Code itself. Anyways thanks for all your comments and queries.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why eslint-plugin-react-hooks doesn't warn when using react hooks conditionally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55892009/why-eslint-plugin-react-hooks-doesnt-warn-when-using-react-hooks-conditionally)

Answer (score 0):

use if inside the `useEffect()`

```
 
useEffect(()=>
  if (trackChanges){
    {   return () => {document.title=`${text1.length}`;}
  }
}, [trackChanges]);
```

Read [this](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) for more info

Comment: Thanks. but my code DOES NOT error out and not quite sure why. If it error out, I was planning to fix it the way you have recommended it. But to my surprise it works perfectky fine

Comment: You need to follow these rules while you working with hooks -> https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Comment: Kalana, please answer my question why it doesn't error in spite of it breaking hook rules. and your code appears to be incorrect as well, we should use if condition inside return () lambda function, isn't it?

Comment: I pointed out how to get rid of the hooks error. I don't know what you are going to achieve by this code.

Comment: I guess I didn't word my question correctly. I am not trying to achieve anything with this code. It is an extremely simplified code where it is easy to understand why it should error but I am not sure why it doesn't. This reduces my confidence that if I make any such mistake in the real code which is not so easy to identify, I will miss it so how to ensure that it is erroring out.

Comment: @Sumanesh does this answer to your question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55892009/why-eslint-plugin-react-hooks-doesnt-warn-when-using-react-hooks-conditionally

Comment: Kalana, now it works perfectly, I can see the ESLint error. Thanks a lot. Much appreciated. Guess need to learn about EsLint more :)

Answer (score 0):

While this is not recommended way of doing things in react but to answer your question on why its not producing an error is because:

React is designed to allow dynamic rendering based on state changes, and it optimizes rendering for performance. In your code, the useEffect hook is conditionally executed based on the value of trackChanges. Initially, trackChanges is set to true, so the effect is registered.

When the user types in the input field, it triggers a state change because of the onChange handler. This change updates the text1 state. Since text1 is listed as a dependency for the useEffect, the effect will run whenever text1 changes. This behavior is expected and works as intended.

However, if you change the value of trackChanges to false, the useEffect will not run, regardless of the changes in text1. React's dependency tracking and optimization allow for this conditional use of useEffect without throwing an error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it doesn't really makes sense on why react hook rules says it shouldn't be used inside a condition. As per the above code when I change flag dynamically it does break when I put more characters on text1 which i can understand why, but it still doesn't make sense why it doesn;t stop me from doing so.

Comment: @Sumanesh: *"why react hook rules says it shouldn't be used inside a condition [...] when I change flag dynamically it does break [...] which i can understand why"* - Then what exactly are you asking?  If breaking the documented rules observably results in an error, and you understand why, then what's the problem?  Are you asking why React doesn't support conditional hooks?  (Which I doubt could be meaningfully answered here, unless someone from the React team happened by.)

Comment: Using hooks conditionally can lead to unexpected behavior and is discouraged because it can make your code harder to understand and maintain. It's generally better to structure your code to consistently use hooks based on dependencies.